# Row ID Column Type : User Maintained - Insert using IFeatureBuffer - ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to insert a record in SDE feature class (which is not registered with SDE) using Arcobjects 10.2 using IFeatureBuffer.InsertFeature functionality. This throws an error message "The current table doesnt have an ArcSDE-maintained rowid column.".

The same code snippet is working fine using Arcobjects 10.0.

Questions:

a) Has IFeatureBuffer interface has changed? ( I don't see any updates in help documentation in ESRI )
b) Is there new rule imposed in SDE to insert a data like Row ID column type should be SDE maintained in 10.2?
c) Is there any impact on altering existing feature class to change the rowid type?
d) Command to alter the feature class rowid column type property?

### Attribute Administration Utility

### Created by layer gen

Table Owner : PROJECT_SCHEMA
Table Name : TABLE1_
Registration Id : 7
Row ID Column : ID
Row ID Column Type : User Maintained
Row Lock : 
Minimum Row ID : 
Dependent Objects : Layer 
Registration Date : Sun Sep 25 20:13:28 2011
Config. Keyword : DEFAULTS
User Privileges : SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
Visibility : Visible